# Some websites dynamically update in a WebView, but others do not

Tags: android, dynamic, webview, animated

I have a pretty standard WebView in which I display web pages.

For instance, when I display:

http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/visualize?nrow=5&ncol=5&pn=p16&hl=fr

or

http://socialwall.bnpparibascardif.com/

both pages will update "dynamically", aka be animated.

But if I display:

http://pennystocks.la/internet-in-real-time/

or

http://pennystocks.la/battle-of-internet-giants/

the pages do not update "dynamically", the numbers do not change.

If I open the same two pages in the standard Android web browser (Android is version 4.4.2 on the device, also tested on another device with 4.4.4), those two last pages are animated as they should be and the numbers change.

Any clue about what that could be, or would it simply be a limitation of WebView?

Thanks!

Comment: Should that be because the second urls/ pages doesn't actually send ajax request ?

Comment: You can debug webviews as well : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 1):

Pages you are using are DOM based modifications , make sure your webview uses javascript.

> `WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
>   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>   webView.loadUrl("http://pennystocks.la/internet-in-real-time/");`

I have tested the above code and it works on the Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Javascript is definitely enabled.
Otherwise, the animations wouldn't work on the other pages either...

Comment: I would like to have a look at your code,since it worked on my phone perfectly ( I saw the data on the tiles being updated )

Comment: Started a new APK from scratch, and it worked for a while... and suddenly, it stopped to work. I suspect something fishy on either Eclipse side or the Android SDK.

Comment: Made a new project from scratch with the same code, and it works again.
It's definitely some Eclipse or SDK issue...